# MFMessageComposeViewController addAttachmentData on iPad iOS7 black screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, imessage

I have a MFMessageComposeController, and I want to send images via iMessage (SMS not available on my iPad).

This is my code:

```
- (void)presentMessageController  {

   if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments])
   {
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                           message:@"Your device doesn't support sharing photos via SMS!"
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
    return;
   }

  MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
  messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;

  [messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG filename:@"image.png"];

  // Present message view controller on screen
  [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem seems to be in **[messageController addAttachmentData...]**. The messageController is not presented, instead a blank screen appears, and app is hanging up, and after 1-2seconds, the delegate responds with MessageComposeResultCancelled, and I see this in console:

**timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose**

**Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!**

If I comment that line, the messageController is presented (iMessage is opened).

IMPORTANT:

1. This is happening when testing on iPad (I tested on iPad 2 only, with iOS 7.0.3 installed). Same code works perfect in iPhone 5, 4, 4S with iOS 7.0.3.
2. When black screen appears, there is no way to return to app. You have to terminate the app, and restart.

Anybody experiencing same issue? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: the code seems to be correct, check if the imgData is not nil

Comment: imgData is not nil. And [messageController addAttachmentData..] is returning YES. So image is attached.

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
[messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG filename:@"image.png"];
```

to:

```
[messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:@"public.data" fileName:@"image.png"];
```

Comment: I just tested, and it has exactly same result. Black screen and hang-up.

Answer (score 0):

Call `presentMessageController` method after some delay

**[self performSelector:@selector(presentMessageController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];**